# Port forward not working for accessing Tomcat

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, tomcat, ports

I have an app running locally on Tomcat that I can access using :

```
http://192.168.192.24:8080/findit/table.html
```

However when I use :

```
http://mypublic-ip-address:8080/findit/table.html
```

I receive error message "This webpage is not available" (tested using Chrome)

I have setup port forwarding as follows :

[image]

Are there any extra steps I should be performing ?

Comment: What OS? If Windows check Windows firewall for the port. Does it work from computers on your LAN?

Comment: @Big Chris I'm using windows 7 , ive added to a rule to allow requests to port 8080. It does work for other computers on LAN using address 192.168.192.24:8080

Comment: Hang on a minute... are you trying to access the page (via your public IP) whilst inside your LAN? What happens when you connect to your Web page using, say, your smartphone with the wifi turned off (3G/4G)?

Comment: @Big Chris accessing with wi-fi turned off works. thanks a million, wasted a few hours banging my head against the router wall. But why ? When connected to network why does it not work ?